# Paypal SDK for iOS version 2.13.2 crash

Tags: ios7, paypal-sandbox

I have used Paypal version 2.13.2 SDK for iOS.The payment with paypal account is working fine but when I am selecting the Pay with card option then the app is crashing.The crash report says 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target

I have imported all the frameworks required for integrating thisSDK.I have also included these 3 libraries i.e libCardIO,libopencv_core,libopencv_imgproc in main bundle.I wonder where the problem is occurring.Do I have to change the SDK and use some previous version of paypal SDK. If I have to use some other SDK please suggest which SDK to use.

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

After couples of work found that. If you optionally choose

`_payPalConfigObj.acceptCreditCards = YES;`

Then you need to add/integrate **"CardIO"** Library to your project. you will be get from ["PayPal Official SDK."](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) **OR** [Separate SDK of 'CardIO'](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK) and Add required frameworks.

Try with above suggestion, defiantly your issue will be solve.

Comment: @RitwikMisra - Good! :)